# How to customize a UISlider with Rubymotion?

Tags: iphone, ios, ruby, rubymotion

Referencing the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can change properties of the UISlider in many ways.

How would you edit a slider in Rubymotion to set for instance a `minimumValueImage`?

```
slider = UISlider.alloc.initWithFrame([[50, 50], [200, 40]])
# ???
```

Comment: Since I posted my question I wrote a whole article on the subject, available here: http://marcgg.com/2012/10/22/custom-slider-ios-rubymotion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mininumValueImage` is a property of UISlider.  So you can set it like this:

```
slider.minimumValueImage = UIImage.imageNamed("sliderMinValueImage")
```

Comment: could you elaborate on the `UIImage`? For instance where I should store them and how do I load them? Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Put the images in the `resources` directory of your app in RubyMotion.  The code shown above loads the image.  You can also put a second image at twice the size with the name `sliderMinValueImage@2x` and that will automatically be loaded when running on retina displays.  I recommend that you use PNG format and you don't have to have `.png` at the end of the PNG filename.